# Date higher than 3 months ago not working mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Hello why this is not working? No matter, date is lower or higher - result always is the same:

```
    const date = new Date();
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - months);
    return this.MongoBackupConnection.db.collection(tableName).find(
    {$or:
        [{'valuesObject.handlowiec6.text': name, 'valuesObject.creation_log.text': {$lte: date}},
        {'valuesObject.handlowiec6.text': name, 'valuesObject.mirror4.text': {$ne: 'Zamontowane'}}]},
    ).sort({'valuesObject.creation_log.text': -1}).toArray();
```

In mongoose record: **text
:
"2021-06-10 15:03:03 UTC"**

Comment: For field value comparison, both the MongoDB document field and the supplied parameter variable should be the same type. Normally date is stored as type `Date`. Sometimes, date is also stored as _string_ data type. Make sure both are of same _type_.

Comment: ehh, now I saw this is string, thank you, so I must do it in code ;/

Comment: You can check the MongoDB field type using the [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operator.

Comment: If the string dates are stored in ISO format YYYY-mm-dd (with always the same number of digits for each component), string sorting *should* work.